# PhoneGap/Cordova ExternalScreen plugin states "External Web View unavailable"

Tags: javascript, cordova, airplay, airserver

I created a PhoneGap/Cordova app for iPad and I want to share specific images from the app via AirPlay to a second screen (A PC or Mac running AirServer (see http://www.airserver.com)).

So I installed the PhoneGap plugin "ExternalScreen":

- Website:
  http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/12/multi-screen-ios-apps-with-phonegap/
- Github: https://github.com/triceam/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ExternalScreen

So within my app I called the following code to see if it works (AirPlay is already connected to AirServer and mirroring is on. I can see the screen content of the iPad on my AirServer instance):

```
PGExternalScreen.loadHTML('HELLO', function(e){
    alert(e);
}, function(){
    alert(e);
});
```

The code above will always alert '**External Web View Unavailable**'.

But the funny thing is, the following code will alert 'available':

```
PGExternalScreen.checkExternalScreenAvailable(function(){
    alert('available');
}, function(){
    alert('not available');
});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I also tried Reflector (http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector) instead of AirServer but same result :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason for this problem. I forgot to call this to initialize

```
PGExternalScreen.setupScreenConnectionNotificationHandlers(success, fail);
```

RTFM, I guess :-(